# Difference between TypeVar('T') and Any

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, typing, type-annotation

Assuming I have some generic function:

```
def foo(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

If I wanted to type hint `*args`, according to the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) I only need to specify the type one arg.

What if the arguments can be of any type? What is the difference between:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

def foo(*args: T):
    ...
```

and

```
def foo(*args: Any):
    ...
```

To my knowledge, `TypeVar('T')` equates to "any type", but does that apply when variable args are of multiple types?

Comment: With a `TypeVar`, you can establish connections between types. Just `TypeVar('T')` itself only means the same as `Any`, `def foo(*args: T) -> T` means `foo` returns the same type as it gets, which you can't express with `Any`…

Comment: @deceze If returning `None`, then there is no difference? If so, I prefer the use of `Any` since its self-explanatory to future readers.

Comment: Short answer is that there's not really any point in using `TypeVar` if you're only using the type in one place and you aren't `bound`ing it.

Answer (score 7):

One could think that the difference is:

`foo(*args: T)` means that the function can take any amount of arguments and the arguments can be of any type but must all be of the same type.

`foo(*args: Any)` means that the function can take any amount of any type arguments.

But this is actually not the case: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6559#issuecomment-473864640

In reality **there is no difference between the two definitions**.

Comment: To your former point, I thought that is what it meant (any type but all the same), but a linter doesn't throw an error when calling `foo('a', 1, ['a', 1])` for example.

Comment: @pasta_sauce Hmm, that is right, `mypy` doesn't seem to consider that as an error. Either I've missed something or it's a bug.

Comment: @pasta_sauce It seems that I am wrong https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6559

Comment: Unless you narrow it further in some way (e.g. with a `bound` or by using the `TypeVar` in a `Generic` so that it can be narrowed by the caller), the type can be arbitrarily broad.  If you replaced `T` with `Union[str, int, List[Union[str, int]]]`, the above usage would typecheck.

Comment: @Samwise Ofc, but that wasn't asked here.

Comment: @Samwise That would typecheck, however thats just an arbitrary example, the type and number of variable arguments is to be unknown.

Comment: I use that example to illustrate how "all of the same type" isn't actually incompatible with "all of different types".  Union types are a thing.  :)